# Can I restrict max_active_runs of a DAG only for runs with the same dag_run.conf?

Tags: airflow

I have a DAG that runs in a multi tenant scenario. The tenant ID get's set in the `dag_run.conf` when the DAG is triggered. I want to ensure that there is at most one active run per tenant at a time, but potentially many active runs simultaneously across all tenants.

So far I have found the `max_active_runs` setting, but that would require me to actually setup one DAG per tenant, which I am trying to avoid.

Is there a way to achieve this in airflow or am I approaching the problem in the wrong way?

Answer (score 1):

You are using `dag_run.conf` which means that you are triggering your dags manually. Currently there is a bug (Airflow 2.0.1) `max_active_runs` isn't respected for manual runs (see [GitHub issue](https://github.com/apache/airflow/issues/9975)).

Comment: Good to know. So even if I were to make one DAG per tenant, it still wouldn't work. Even more reason to find another way then.

Comment: if you make 1 dag per tenant than you won't have this issue because your workflow is manual trigger so you can see that a dag is currently in progress and in that case you will not trigger it.

Comment: Well, it's not truly manual, it's through the API, so I'd need to make the service that calls the API check if it's currently running. Which, while possible, is a little more cumbersome than just setting a parameter to 1 and having airflow take care of it. But I get your point.